# launch screen can not change the image

Tags: ios, screen, launch

i just want my launch screen show a image ,so i drag a image view into the launch screen.storyboard.  and the first time it works as what i want . 
now i have something change on the image, so i delete the pre image ,and drag the new image into the assert.xcassets , but the result is the image never change ,still be the pre one ,i have tried clean the project, and checked whether the image is the new one in my project assets dir. no one works.
is this a bug or i missed something, **this can be reproduce  ,everybody can try it .**thanks for any help.
[image: the origin image]

and the new image   has some text on it , when i  delete the origin image and dragged new one, the new one never appeared, still the old image
[image]

Comment: try deleting the app from the target, clean build and run.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg  not works, now it shows noting (a blank area) instead of the  pre image ,i have tried other UIView (label button), they all working correctly  except something relative to the image (example: button image , image view)

Comment: click the project and then check the "app icons and launch Images" option , have you set the launch image properly

Comment: @Abdul Karim  they all set correctly , i even have tried a new storyboard or xib ,and config them in the  "app icons and launch Images",but not works